# Separate csv file paths with specific seed and speed number using Python

Tags: python

I am facing a problem where I have a list of csv file paths. I need to separate CSV file paths on the basis of specific mode with different seed and same speed using Python.
Naming convention is something like this:

Absolute Path of CSV file/(mode)(seed)(speed).csv

csv_filepaths = ['C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha_586893215_speed0.csv', 'C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha_586893215_speed4.csv', 'C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha2_123456787_speed0.csv', 'C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha2_123456787_speed4.csv', 'C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha2_886589746_speed0.csv', 'C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha2_886589746_speed4.csv', 'C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/beta1_52186893215_speed0.csv', 'C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/beta1_52186893215_speed4.csv', 'C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/beta1_86893215_speed0.csv', 'C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/beta1_86893215_speed4.csv']

I want output like this:

```
['C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha_586893215_speed0.csv']
['C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha_2_123456787_speed0.csv', 'C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha_2_886589746_speed0.csv']
['C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/beta_1_52186893215_speed0.csv', 'C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/beta_1_86893215_speed0.csv']
['C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha_586893215_speed4.csv']
['C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha_2_123456787_speed4.csv', 'C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha_2_886589746_speed4.csv']
['C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/beta_1_52186893215_speed4.csv', 'C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/beta_1_86893215_speed4.csv']
```

Comment: I do not understand the logic behind your desired output, Which paths should be in tha same list? Which ones should be separate? The output of the code looks fine, every combination of mode and seed is in a separate list.

Comment: Matteo I want same mode, different seed, same speed in a separate list, like you can see alpha_2 mode has 2 different seeds and speeds, I want alpha_2 mode with seed #1 speed #1 and aplha_2 mode with seed #2 and speed #2

Comment: Lets forget about my approach and my current output, how can I achieve the desired output results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the unique key identifing each list has to be the combination of **mode** and **speed** then I would suggest creating a dictionary using that as key and keep a list of all the paths that correspond to that key.

```py
csv_filepaths = [
    "C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha_586893215_speed0.csv",
    "C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha_586893215_speed4.csv",
    "C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha2_123456787_speed0.csv",
    "C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha2_123456787_speed4.csv",
    "C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha2_886589746_speed0.csv",
    "C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/alpha2_886589746_speed4.csv",
    "C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/beta1_52186893215_speed0.csv",
    "C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/beta1_52186893215_speed4.csv",
    "C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/beta1_86893215_speed0.csv",
    "C:/Users/DELL/Documents/abc/beta1_86893215_speed4.csv",
]

output = {}
for f in csv_filepaths:
    *_, filename = f.split("/")  # get the filename form the complete path
    filename, _ = filename.split(".")  # remove the extension
    mode, seed, speed = filename.split("_")
    output.setdefault((mode, speed), []).append(f)

for out in output.values():
    print(out)
```

> NOTE: the line `output.setdefault((mode, speed), []).append(f)` is just a  shorthand for
>
> ```py
> if (mode, speed) in output:
>     output[(mode, speed)].append(f)
> else:
>     output[(mode, speed)] = [f]
> ```

A better approch to get the filename out of the list would be to use a library like `os.path` or `pathlib` (my personal choiche would be the latter) but here I included a naive way without libraries since path operations was not the focus of your question.

Comment: Thank you Zanoni. It worked really well.